# Eclipse RCP ContentAssistProcessor not working

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I implemented my custom editor with my own `TextSourceViewerConfiguration`.
So I want to add two content assistant processors.

```
   public IContentAssistant getContentAssistant(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
      ContentAssistant assistant = new ContentAssistant();
      IContentAssistProcessor pr = new MyFirstContentAssistProcessor();
      IContentAssistProcessor dr = new MySecondContentAssistProcessor();
      assistant.setContextInformationPopupOrientation(IContentAssistant.CONTEXT_INFO_ABOVE);
      assistant.setContentAssistProcessor(pr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
      assistant.setContentAssistProcessor(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
      return assistant;
   }
```

Only `MyFirstContentAssistProcessor` works. But I need both.

When I make

```
assistant.addContentAssistProcessor(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE)

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.add(AbstractCollection.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant.addContentAssistProcessor(ContentAssistant.java:1147)
    at testingpluginproject.editors.XMLConfiguration.getContentAssistant(XMLConfiguration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.configure(SourceViewer.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3385)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:361)
```

Comment: The second call should be `addContentAssistProcessor` not `setContentAssistProcessor`

Comment: But when I change it to   assistant.addContentAssistProcessor(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
Then I got exception because the key ist already forgiven.
When I make so ssistant.addContentAssistProcessor(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE + "New"); does not work

Comment: Show us a stack trace of the exception, you need to get add to work with the same document type.

Comment: adding the stacktrace above

Comment: I got it, assistant.addContentAssistProcessor(pr,Document.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE)     assistant.addContentAssistProcessor(dr,IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYP);
Before I had
      assistant.setContentAssistProcessor(pr,IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
 assistant.addContentAssistProcessor(dr,Document.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
Thx